# Prisma - Error Creating Relationships Between Models

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

I'm new to SQL databases. I'm attempting to create a latestMessage field on the Conversation model, which should reference the Message model. However, every time I try to establish the opposite relation, I encounter more errors. Is there a more efficient way to relate these two models?

models:

```
model Message {
id              Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
sender          User           @relation(fields: \[user_id\], references: \[id\])
message         String
user_id         Int            @default(autoincrement())
conversation    Conversation   @relation(fields: \[conversation_id\], references: \[id\])
conversation_id Int            @default(autoincrement())
creation_date   DateTime       @default(now())
updated_at      DateTime       @updatedAt
Conversation    Conversation\[\]
}

model Conversation {
id              Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
name            String
image           String    @default("defaultGroup.png")
users           User\[\]
messages        Message\[\]
latestMessage   Message?  @relation("LatestMessage", fields: \[latestMessageId\], references: \[id\])
latestMessageId Int?
creation_date   DateTime  @default(now())
updated_at      DateTime  @updatedAt
}
```

Prisma Error :

```
Error validating model "Message": Ambiguous relation detected. The fields `conversation` and `Conversation` in model `Message` both refer to `Conversation`. Please provide different relation names for them by adding \`@relation( ).
```